# A and an usage and difference

Tags: articles

This is an excerpt from newspaper.
Without a overhang of heavy handed security.
Why does the author use a and not an?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a typographical error.

Answer (score 1):

It's an error/typo.  Overhang begins with a phonetic vowel sound so it should be preceded by 'an'.

Comment: Was it *really* worth posting an actual *answer?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - What would you have preferred?  Closing the question unanswered?  Leaving a comment saying the same thing?  The two sentence answer is hardly an effort, and I don't believe the question was asked out of laziness or malice or anything similar, but rather confusion caused by the common belief that if something is printed in a respectable source like a newspaper that it has been reviewed enough to be grammatical.

Comment: In a case like this I'd prefer to go with @choster's approach (provide the "answer" within closevote text). It may never happen, but I can see merit in *automatically* deleting On Hold questions with no answers after, say, 6 months. I never agreed with TPTB doing away with Too Localised in the first place, and I really don't see how this page is likely to be useful to any future visitors. So it's quite possible I'll eventually end up throwing my vote in to "manually" delete it.